# CANNOT_REPARENT_RECORD: Before you can make this contact private, you must remove its relationships to other accounts

Tags: visual-workflow, contact, field-update

I'm receiving the following error when trying to update an existing Contact's AccountId to null

[image]

This has been working fine in the past but now it gives me the following error:

**CANNOT_REPARENT_RECORD: Before you can make this contact private, you must remove its relationships to other accounts**

I've been searching for a related article on this topic but no luck. Has anyone encountered this error before and can guide me in order to understand it and fix it?

Regards,

Comment: Sounds like you have enabled Contacts to Multiple Accounts, have you checked this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.shared_contacts_set_up.htm&type=5) already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "CANNOT_REPARENT_RECORD: Before you can make this contact private, you must remove its relationships to other accounts" occurs when you are trying to update a Contact record in Salesforce and set the AccountId field to null, but the Contact record is still associated with other Account records.

This error message is telling you that before you can set the AccountId field to null, you must first remove any existing relationships between the Contact record and other Account records. This means that you will need to update any Account records that are related to the Contact record and remove the Contact's ID from the related list of Contacts on those Account records.

Once you have removed the relationships between the Contact record and other Account records, you should be able to update the Contact record and set the AccountId field to null without encountering the error message.